# If $n$ is a multiperfect number, then necessarily does one of its prime factors $p$ satisfy $p \parallel n$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples, perfect-numbers

My question is as in the title:

> If $n$ is a multiperfect number, then necessarily does one of its prime factors $p$ satisfy $p \parallel n$?

I quote from an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3784544/28816) by [Varun Vejalla](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/595055) to a closely related MSE question:

> I checked all the multiperfect numbers from [this site](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/mpn.html), which include all the multiperfect numbers in the b-file of [A007691](http://oeis.org/A007691), as well as additional ones. The largest number that was in the list was $\approx 10^{34850339}$. None of those values were perfect powers.

> What I did find for all multiperfect numbers is that there was at least one prime factor with an exponent of exactly $1$ in the prime factorization. If this could be proved for all multiperfect numbers, then the conjecture that there is no number that is both multiperfect and a perfect power could be proven.

Comment: While likely to be true, it is not known if multi perfect numbers are never powerful. Indeed, if a perfect number is a perfect power, Euler tells us that the number is odd and is a (4k+1) power for some k.  It might be useful to see what is known about primitive factors of sigma(p^e) for increasing exponents e and primes p. Even such a result for perfect numbers is unknown, let alone multi perfects.  Gerhard "One Is Too Multi Perfect" Paseman, 2020.08.08.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman, it is known that perfect numbers cannot be perfect powers.  (See this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3783461) for the details.)

Comment: What details? There is only an assertion.  Gerhard "Not Ready To Suspend Disbelief" Paseman, 2020.08.08.